# Import complex data type(Array) from csv to snappydata

Tags: apache-spark-sql, snappydata

From my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052483/how-to-store-array-or-blob-in-snappydata/47060209?noredirect=1#comment81083969_47060209) I came to know the way one can insert array.

Now I want to insert a latge amount of data into the table. From this [reference](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/reference/sql_reference/create-external-table/) of snappydata i was able to import a large amount into the tables. But when i tried to import complex data type like Array it isn't supporting.

```
CSV sample:
'name',1,[1,2,4]
or
'name',1,array(1,2,4)
```

Can anyone tell me how can I insert array into table from CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above question by converting the CSV to JSON. I followed the [documentation](https://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/store_and_query_json_objects/#how-to-store-and-query-json-objects) for json to snappydata.